# URL Rewrite iis server

Tags: regex, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to rewrite a url to index.html. the web.config below does the job until first path.
eg:- test.com/test1 to test.com/index.html but it doesnt work with multiple paths. eg:- test.com/test1/test2

my current web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Please if any of you know, write the correct web.config.
Thank you.

Comment: FRT can guide you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">                    
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/([^/]+)" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://test.com/{C:1}/index.com" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```